# Double Integral Mistake with Parametric Equation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to figure out the mass of an object bounded by $y=0$ and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ the density at a given point is proportional to its distance from the origin; $\rho(x,y) = kxy$. So I set it up like this: $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}kr^3\sin(\theta)cos(\theta)\,\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$ Unfortunately I'm getting 0, I think this is because my density function is becoming negative in the second quadrant. I know that using the absolute value in my density function will probably solve my problem but how do I do that?

Comment: If your density is proportional to distance from origin, why $\rho=kxy$?

Comment: "the density at a given point is proportional to its distance from the origin" should be $\rho(x,y)=k\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense that it should be like a circle. I think I did it this way because my last problem had to be proportional from the $x$ axis so I just used $kx$. Come to think of that problem I probably should have done $ky$.

Comment: Are you missing any thing like "mass of an object bounded by y = 0 and $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ **rotated about y axis**.

Comment: No, I don't think we're quite there yet.